# Not getting all the changes from team foundation Orchard (Content item, navigation)

Tags: c#-4.0, tfs, orchardcms

When retrieving a project on my laptop through team foundation server i cannot seem to get anything admin related created from the dashboard.

For example navigation or content types / items are not being shown.
My custom theme for example and all the other modules are properly integrated.

Where are all those content items located and why is it not properly committed into team foundation server?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to provide a lot more details if you hope to get a useful answer.

Comment: For example i added a navigation menu and content items through the admin dashboard on my desktop. Followed by a check in into tfs. When getting the lattest version of the project on my laptop none of these changes are visible. Do i need to add specific items to the source control? No idea how To provide more info about this issue Bertrand.

Comment: Changes that are stored in the database are not going to be taken by source control, no, of course. In order to deploy data changes, you need to use import/export or database backups.

Comment: Cheers Bertrand, what would be the best way of backing up the SQL Compact database with Orchard? I have copied the 4 files from the location Orchard\src\Orchard.Web\App_Data\Sites\Default and placed this on my other computer, but this seems the wrong and hacky approach? Or is the import/export module all i need for database back-up purposes? Thanks!

Comment: Import/Export works well for recreating a site populated with data etc. But copying the entire App_Data folder is good for just backing up stuff.

Comment: The easiest way to backup the SQL Compact database is to copy the file, yes. Why do you see that as a problem?

Comment: Was thinking about security issues when the sites goes live in production, but those are concerns for later. The Import/Export module resulted in errors since some journals were not found, guess i'm going for the copy solution (faster and easier). Thanks for the given input!